# Как мне перенести импортированные данные из datagridview в MS sql

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

В пустой datagridview я получил данные из Excel таблицы и хочу его сохранить в таблице. Как мне это сделать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам код Form:

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    //Подключение к бд
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-CG70ETG; Initial Catalog=wsrdzudo; Integrated Security=True;");
    //Запрос
    string query = "Select * From Participants";
    SqlDataAdapter adapter;
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

    private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Импорт данных из Ecxel
        OpenFileDialog opf = new OpenFileDialog();
        opf.Filter = "Excel File(*.xlsx;*.xls)|*.xlsx;*.xls|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
        opf.ShowDialog();
        DataTable tb = new DataTable();
        string filename = opf.FileName;
        string ConStr = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;", filename);
        System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet("EXCEL");
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(ConStr);
        con.Open();
        DataTable schemaTable = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
        string sheet1 = (string)schemaTable.Rows[0].ItemArray[2];
        string select = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", sheet1);
        OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter(select, con);
        ad.Fill(ds);
        tb = ds.Tables[0];
        con.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = tb;
    }
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        adapter.Update((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Подключение к бд
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-CG70ETG; Initial Catalog=wsrdzudo; Integrated Security=True;";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            //Запрос на удаление
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Participants WHERE Participants_id= @id", con);
            int id = int.Parse(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            con.Open();
            try
            {
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Запись удалена");
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Удалить не удалось!");
            }
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)
                    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString().Contains(textBox1.Text))
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = true;
                        break;
                    }
        }
    }

    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "wsrdzudoDataSet.Participants". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
        this.participantsTableAdapter.Fill(this.wsrdzudoDataSet.Participants);

    }
}
```

Comment: Стандартная команда sql INSERT. По аналогии с имеющейся у вас DELETE.

Comment: При чём тут вообще DataGridView и WinForms? Абстрагируйтесь от лишнего! У вас есть **данные**. Вы считали их (SELECT) из Excel в `DataTable`. Теперь вставьте их в БД (INSERT) из этого `DataTable`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я не понял как правильно составить правильный запрос. Можете на примере разобрать? Буду благодарен.